# How to cast int to string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this: `COALESCE(amount ,0) as amount`. The data type for `amount` is `numeric`.

Instead of `0` I want `N/A`. How can I do that? I am getting errors:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "N/A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case more suited this code: `coalesce(cast(nullif(amount, 0) as text), 'N/A')`

And additional about saving:

```
case 
  when coalesce(cast(nullif(a.amount1, 0) as text), 'N/A') = 'N/A' then 'N/A' 
  when coalesce(cast(nullif(a.amount2, 0) as text), 'N/A') = 'N/A' then 'N/A'  
  else (coalesce(cast(nullif(a.amount1 - a.amount2, 0) as text), 'N/A')) 
end as savings
```

Comment: i have further question. I want to use the above column say that column is     Coalesce(cast(nullif(amount, 0) as text), 'N/A') as rate and then I want to use another column which will use that column and say savings and it is calculation on this column and other column. if amount is  'N/A' then in savings it should say 'N/A' else the calculation. i used same expression and getting error on that one. It is like (COALESCE(amount1,0) - COALESCE(amount2,0))  as savings

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, you want to add a alias. then just add it after the string `as amount`

Comment: this is the error I am getting: operator does not exist: text - text

Comment: this is I am using  ( Coalesce(cast(nullif(a.amount1, 0) as text), 'N/A')) - (Coalesce(cast(nullif(a.amount2, 0) as text), 'N/A'))  as savings and this is the error I am getting: operator does not exist: text - text

Comment: I've understand. for it use `(coalesce(cast(nullif(a.amount1- a.amount2, 0) as text), 'N/A')) as savings`

Comment: That is not all say me pls in columns `a.amount1` and `a.amount2` might be text? for example 'N/A' or ther is available null, 0 and other numerics

Comment: so for amount1=$22 or amount2=$10  savings is $12. this can be simple amount1-amount2 . But another case if amount1 is 0 we want to show it as 'N/A' and so amount1='N/A' amount2=14 savings ='N/A'  .how can we get 'N/A' in savings

Comment: @user3438498 check my answer, I've updated it, Upvote answer if it helps to you =)

Comment: @user3438498 it helps to you?

Answer (score 9):

Use a type cast:

```
coalesce(CAST(amount AS text), 'N/A')
```